# Array count, sum and order in one step

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that represents soccer match "results" (**team1** - the name represented by a number and **team1_points** that represents how many points this team earn from this match (3 for win, 1 for draw and 0 for lost).

Here is the code:

```
  array (size=9)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'team1' => string '2' (length=1)
      'team1_points' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'team1' => string '2' (length=1)
      'team1_points' => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'team1' => string '2' (length=1)
      'team1_points' => string '0' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'team1' => string '14' (length=2)
      'team1_points' => string '0' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'team1' => string '14' (length=2)
      'team1_points' => string '3' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'team1' => string '1' (length=1)
      'team1_points' => string '3' (length=1)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'team1' => string '13' (length=2)
      'team1_points' => string '1' (length=1)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'team1' => string '5' (length=1)
      'team1_points' => string '1' (length=1)
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      'team1' => string '7' (length=1)
      'team1_points' => string '0' (length=1)
```

As you can see some of the **team1** are repeating like **'team1' => '2'** is there 3 times and team with id="14" is there 2 times **'team1' => '14'** etc.

I need to group the same teams based on **team1** column (teams with the same id e.g. 2 or 14 etc. and create a new alias column called e.g. **team_1_occurrences** tht will hold the number of that team in the array and also a column e.g. **team1_total_points** that will SUM all the **team1_points** (3,1 or 0).

And then order by team1_total_points column DESC.

So, in the end I need something like this:

```
team1 | team1_occurrences | team1_total_points
----------------------------------------------
14    | 2                 | 3
----------------------------------------------
2     | 3                 | 0
```

...

My array created from while loop contains only 2 columns **team1** and **team1_points** (the result is the var_dump in the beginning of my question:

```
$matches_array[] = array(
     'team1'=> $team_1_id,
     'team1_points'=> $team1_points
);
```

I guess I need somehow use the php function **array_count_values** and create a new column but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance for any advice how to solve this.

Comment: Now, what is your problem in doing so?

Comment: Wait, I will update my question with my current code to be more clear.

Comment: Again, what's the problem? Also, are you getting the data from a database? If so, then it's much more easier and also efficient to do the stuff in the DB-level.

Comment: Ok, updated. My problem is that I don't know which functions should I use for accomplishing what I need. Therefore I am asking here for some advice.

Comment: No, I am using pods framework for WP and they have a bug there so I can't use count or sum because it keeps prepending t. prefix etc. it's a long story. I need to bypass it for now using arrays.

Comment: Now the question is even more confusing. What is "team1" – just a label or an identifier for a team (e.g. #14 & #2)? Where do you get those data from? Do you have database to pull these data from?

Comment: @Derfder "I need to bypass it for now using arrays." Well, you should really fix the underlying problem or query the database directly with a custom query – which is possible in WP.

Comment: You don't understand. The whole core PODS framework team is trying to fix it now so the next version 2.0.4 will be ok, but I can't wait so I am using arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$array = array(
        0 => array('team1' => '2','team1_points' => '1'),
        1 => array('team1' => '2','team1_points' => '1'),
        2 => array('team1' => '2','team1_points' => '0'),
        3 => array('team1' => '14','team1_points' => '0'),
        4 => array('team1' => '14','team1_points' => '3'),
        5 => array('team1' => '1','team1_points' => '3'),
        6 => array('team1' => '13','team1_points' => '1'),
        7 => array('team1' => '5','team1_points' => '1'),
        8 => array('team1' => '7','team1_points' => '1'));



$list = array();

array_map(function($var){}, $array);
foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    $key = $value['team1'];

    if (array_key_exists($key, $list)) {
        $list[$key]['team1_points'] += $value['team1_points'];
        $list[$key]['team_1_occurrences'] ++;
    } else {
        $list[$key] = $value;
        $list[$key]['team_1_occurrences'] = 1;
    }
}

usort($list ,function($a, $b){ $a = $a['team1_points'] ; $b = $b['team1_points'] ; return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? 1 : -1 ) ;});
var_dump($list);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'team1' => string '14' (length=2)
      'team1_points' => int 3
      'team_1_occurrences' => int 2
  1 => 
    array
      'team1' => string '1' (length=1)
      'team1_points' => string '3' (length=1)
      'team_1_occurrences' => int 1
  2 => 
    array
      'team1' => string '2' (length=1)
      'team1_points' => int 2
      'team_1_occurrences' => int 3
  3 => 
    array
      'team1' => string '7' (length=1)
      'team1_points' => string '1' (length=1)
      'team_1_occurrences' => int 1
  4 => 
    array
      'team1' => string '13' (length=2)
      'team1_points' => string '1' (length=1)
      'team_1_occurrences' => int 1
  5 => 
    array
      'team1' => string '5' (length=1)
      'team1_points' => string '1' (length=1)
      'team_1_occurrences' => int 1
```

Comment: @Derfder let me know if you need any improvement

Comment: So far it seems to work. I think the only problem is with e.g. 'team_1_occurrences' => int 0 it should be 'team_1_occurrences' => int 1 . Do you think that adding 1 for every occurence will solve it?

Comment: The updated code gives me an error: Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array :(. Any advice how to fix it?

Comment: nevermind, I forget to include $list - array(); Now it works. However, how to sort it based on points instead of occurences

Comment: And other thing sometimes in the var_dump it is  'team1_points' => string '3' (length=1) and sometimes just 'team1_points' => int 3 . Why?

Comment: @Derfder see updated code `team_1_occurrences` has been corrected

Comment: Thanks, occurences are now ok. but How to order the array by points and not by occurences?

Comment: Hmm, seems not to work still ordered by occurencies insteaad of points

Comment: OK thanks now it is working when I change it to points like this : usort($list ,function($a, $b){ $a = $a['team1_points'] ; $b = $b['team1_points'] ; return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? 1 : -1 ) ;});

Answer (score 0):

```
function cmp_by_teampoints($a, $b) {
        return $b["points"] - $a["points"] ;
}

$mr = array(
    array('team1' => '2','team1_points' => '1'),
    array('team1' => '2','team1_points' => '1'),
    array('team1' => '2','team1_points' => '0'),
    array('team1' => '14','team1_points' => '0'),
    array('team1' => '14','team1_points' => '3'),
    array('team1' => '1','team1_points' => '3'),
    array('team1' => '13','team1_points' => '1'),
    array('team1' => '5','team1_points' => '1'),
    array('team1' => '7','team1_points' => '1'));
$s = array();
foreach ($mr as $t => $r) {
    $key = $r['team1'];
    if(!isset($s[$key])) {
        $s[$key]['team']=$key;
        $s[$key]['points']+=$r['team1_points'];
        $s[$key]['occurrence']=1;
    }
    else {
        $s[$key]['points']+=$r['team1_points'];
        $s[$key]['occurrence']++;
    }
}

usort($s, "cmp_by_teampoints");
```